# How to set Visual Studio C++ "default default" project settings

Tags: c++, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

How do I change the default settings (property pages) that new "Solutions" and projects start with? When I create a new project using the Application Wizard, it always has the same settings, but they are not the ones I want.

Surely the question must have been asked and answered, but I cannot find it. Maybe I do not know the right jargon.

Comment: Do try to be at least a *little* specific about what you are unhappy about.  In VS2013 and up use File > Export Template to create your own project templates.  Tinkering with the files that the wizard generates is technically possible to some degree, you can edit VC\VCWizards\common.js.  Be sure to make a backup.

Comment: I wouldn't say I am unhappy. It's just that whenever I start a new C++ project, I have to go through the properties manually changing the same settings I always change. VC++2017RC does not have anything under File->Export Template. I did however find something under Tools->Import and Export Settings. Maybe that's the ticket.

Comment: I got here looking for similar things.  For each new project, there are always several settings I want changed.  For example, I want character set set to Unicode by default, I want the warning level set to 4, and I want to treat warnings as errors.  There are a few others as well, but this gives the idea.  The .js files @Hans Passant talks about have what looks like a signature at the bottom, which makes me wonder if I can change the settings without breaking some validation step.

Comment: @adr: Even though Unicode character set and /W4 are defaults now (at least in Visual Studio 2019), you may still be interested to hear, that custom project templates are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio allows you to generate a custom project template, allowing you to set the defaults to what makes the most sense for any given environment.

The procedure involves 2 steps:

- Create a new project, and adjust the settings.
- Export a template using the *Export Template Wizard*. Up until Visual Studio 2015, the *Export Template...* command was under the *File* menu. Starting with Visual Studio 2017, it was moved to the *Project* menu.

  On the first page, select *Project template*, and continue on to the next (final) page, filling in the information as appropriate. Choose *Automatically import the template into Visual Studio* to have it instantly available.

Official documentation is available at [How to: Create project templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2019).